# Tabbed page flicker in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on tabbed pages, I am getting flicker issue while loading tabbed page. When I start the application, after splash screen my tabbed page will appear, In that page I have initialize the local database and getting user details from server. flicker issue is very problematic in my tabbed page. I have set the image will cover the total screen in this screen, Due to that image flicker effect is easy to visible all user. How can we resolve these flicker effect, Please suggest any idea.

Sample code:

xaml page:

```
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
  <Grid>
  <Image x:Name = "Image" Source = "{Binding ImageSource}" IsVisible="{Binding IosImageVisibility}" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" Aspect = "AspectFill"/>
  <StackLayout Padding = "10" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
   <Label Text="Sample test? " VerticalOptions="Fill" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" >
        <Label.FontSize>
          <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="26" Tablet ="35"/>
        </Label.FontSize>
      </Label>
    </Grid>
 </StackLayout>
```

xaml.cs :

```
    public partial class SampleView()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      BindingContext = new SampleViewModel();
      LoadBackgroundImages();
    }

    private async void LoadBackgroundImages()
    {
        Image.Source = "sample.jpg";
        await TaskDelay(2000);
        Image.Source = "sample2.jpg";
        await TaskDelay(2000);
        Image.Source = "sample2.jpg";
        await TaskDelay(2000);
    }

    private void RepeatLoop()
    {
        LoadBackgroundImages();
    }
```

SampleViewModel

```
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
       InitializeDataBase();
       GetUserDetailsFromServer();
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code ?

Comment: Hi  Felix D. I have added my sample code

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem, could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem?